# Javafx widget not responding after switching FXML

Tags: java, fxml, javafx-11

My javafx application has to switch its FXML file after the selection of an item in a combo box The combo box however stops responding after switching but the other items added by the FXML continue to work. I have to either minimise and maximise the application to make it work or use the widgets added by the FXML to make it responsive.

```
comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
        calculatorType = comboBox.getValue();
        switch (calculatorType) {
            case "Basic":
                System.out.println(root.getChildren());
                root.getChildren().clear();
                try {
                    stage.setMinWidth(430);
                    stage.setMinHeight(530);
                    stage.setMaxWidth(430);
                    stage.setMinHeight(530);
                    //root.getChildren().remove(comboBox);
                    root.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Calculator/Resources" +
                            "/BasicCalculator.fxml")));
                    comboBox.setLayoutX(320);
                    comboBox.setLayoutY(0);
                    root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "Scientific":
                root.getChildren().clear();
                try {
                    stage.setMinHeight(530);
                    stage.setMinWidth(780);
                    stage.setMaxHeight(530);
                    stage.setMaxWidth(780);
                    root.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Calculator/Resources/" +
                            "ScientificCalculator.fxml")));
                    comboBox.setLayoutX(675);
                    comboBox.setLayoutY(0);
                    root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "Converter":
                root.getChildren().clear();
                stage.setMinHeight(530);
                stage.setMinWidth(430);
                stage.setMaxHeight(530);
                stage.setMaxWidth(430);
                try {
                    root.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Calculator/Resources/" +
                                "Converter.fxml")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                comboBox.setLayoutX(320);
                comboBox.setLayoutY(0);
                root.getChildren().add(ComboPane);
                break;
        }
});
```

The combo box is in main.

The code for combo box:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getStylesheets().add("Calculator/Resources/Styles/ComboBox.css");
        comboBox.getItems().add("Basic");
        comboBox.getItems().add("Scientific");
        comboBox.getItems().add("Converter");
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        comboBox.setLayoutX(320);
        comboBox.setLayoutY(0);
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a different design. Below are two possibilities.

- Make each type of calculator a separate [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) and just switch `Scene`s by calling method [setScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setScene-javafx.scene.Scene-). Note that you may probably need to add the `ComboBox` to each `Scene`.
- Alternatively, make each calculator a separate [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and add each of those `Pane`s to a [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html). Switch between the calculator `Pane`s by making the selected calculator's `Pane` [visible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty) and all the others invisible.